# ¿Por qué cuando inserto un registro en mysql desde Javafx me agrega una nueva columna de Atributos?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Es decir tengo 10 atributos iniciales los cuales quiero agregar a mi bd uno es el id que se genera automáticamente y los demás son columnas normales.
Pero cuando hago la acción de insertar en la bd ya no hay 10 atributos iniciales sino que se modifica a 11 y quiero evitar que eso suceda.

Éste es el método de Agregado, es muy sencillo:

```
public void registrar() {
        alumno = new registrar_alumno_modelo(0, txtNombreA.getText());
        service.addAlumno(alumno);
}
```

Este es el constructor de la entidad a la que le estoy agregando los atributos

```
@Entity(name="alumno")
public class registrar_alumno_modelo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;


    @Column(name="NombreA")
    private String nombre ;

/*  @Column(name="Apellidos")
    private String apellidos;

    @Column(name="Edad")
    private int edad;

    @Column(name="FechaN")
    private Date fecha;

    @Column(name="Sexo")
    private String sexo;

    @Column(name="Nota")
    private String nota;

    @Column(name="Generacion")
    private int generacion;

    @Column(name="NickName")
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name="Password")
    private String pass;
*/
    public registrar_alumno_modelo(int id, String nombre) {
      super();
      this.id = id;
      this.nombre = nombre;
/*    this.apellidos = apellidos;
      this.edad = edad;
      this.fecha = fecha;
      this.sexo = sexo;
      this.nota = nota;
      this.generacion = generacion;
      this.usuario = Usuario;
      this.pass = pass;*/
    }

    public registrar_alumno_modelo() {
        this(0, "");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

/*  public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }



    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }

    public String getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(String nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    public int getGeneracion() {
        return generacion;
    }

    public void setGeneracion(int generacion) {
        this.generacion = generacion;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }*/

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "alumno [id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + "]";
    }
}
```

Ahora muestro algunas líneas documentadas porque quise hacer la prueba solo con dos elementos el id y el nombre pero me sigue marcando el mismo error:

Este es mi Servicio:

```
private registro_alumno alumnoDao= new registro_alumno_Imp();


@Override
public void addAlumno(registrar_alumno_modelo alumno) {
    alumnoDao.addAlumno(alumno);

}
```

Este es mi DAO:

```
@Override
public void addAlumno(registrar_alumno_modelo alumno) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(alumno);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo *id* esta anotado como *@GeneratedValue* esto significa que en MySQL el campo primary key debe tener la propiedad AUTOINCREMENT.

Lo siguiente es que no debes asignar valor a esa propiedad, es decir, tu constructor no debe tenerlo en cuenta, debe quedar así:

```
@Entity(name="alumno")
public class registrar_alumno_modelo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public int id;

  @Column(name="NombreA")
  private String nombre ;

  public registrar_alumno_modelo(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
  }

}
```

Hibernate junto con la bd se encargan de generar el valor adecuado cuando se realiza el insert de una entidad